# Python pyqt sender state handling

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt

I have to disable some widgets according to checkbox state. Widgets and checkboxes have similar names: `checkP0`, `minP0`, etc.
Is there more elegant way to do this than I did?
I am pyqt and python beginner. Thanks a lot.

```
def checkboxes (self, state):

    if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        name = self.sender().objectName()
        mod = "self.mod" + name[-2:] + ".setDisabled(False)"
        min = "self.min" + name[-2:] + ".setDisabled(False)"
        max = "self.max" + name[-2:] + ".setDisabled(False)"
        exec str(mod)
        exec str(min)
        exec str(max)
    else:
        name = self.sender().objectName()
        mod = "self.mod" + name[-2:] + ".setDisabled(True)"
        min = "self.min" + name[-2:] + ".setDisabled(True)"
        max = "self.max" + name[-2:] + ".setDisabled(True)"
        exec str(mod)
        exec str(min)
        exec str(max)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very rare that `exec` or `eval` are the right tools for the job, so your first instinct should always be to avoid them if at all possible.

In this particular case, you could use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#getattr) and a loop, instead:

```
def checkboxes (self, state):
    suffix = self.sender().objectName()[-2:]
    enable = state == QtCore.Qt.Checked
    for prefix in 'mod', 'min', 'max':
        getattr(self, prefix + suffix).setEnabled(enable)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I knew that exec is bad, therefore I asked for help :)